# Symbol 'type org.mongodb.scala.bson.package.Document' is missing from the classpath

Tags: mongodb, scala, gradle

I am new to Scala, trying to write MongoDB crud example, ended up getting below error. could you please let me know what is missing? here is my github: https://github.com/ravisuthar/My-Gradle-Scala-MongoDB

first scala code

```
   package com.example
    
    import org.mongodb.scala.{Document, MongoClient, MongoCollection, MongoDatabase}
    
    object App {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    
        val client: MongoClient = MongoClient()
        val database: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase("latest_db")
        val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("students")
    
        // insert a document
        val document: Document = Document("name" -> "John", "age" -> 51)
        val insertObservable = collection.insertOne(document)
        println("Document inserted")
    
        // find documents
        collection.find()
          .collect()
          .subscribe((results: Seq[Document]) => println(s"Found: #${results.size}"))
      }
    }
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb.scala', name: 'mongo-scala-driver_2.13', version: '4.10.2'
    implementation group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-reactivestreams', version: '4.10.2'
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.10'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.13:3.2.15'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatestplus:junit-4-13_2.13:3.2.2.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.13:1.2.0'
}
```

failure logs:

```
> Task :app:compileKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileJava NO-SOURCE

> Task :app:compileScala
[Error] /app/src/main/scala/com/example/App.scala:13:37: Symbol 'type org.mongodb.scala.bson.package.Document' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'type org.mongodb.scala.Document'.
Make sure that type Document is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.mongodb.scala.bson.package.
[Error] /app/src/main/scala/com/example/App.scala:13:49: Symbol 'term org.mongodb.scala.bson.DefaultHelper' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value org.mongodb.scala.MongoDatabase.e'.
Make sure that term DefaultHelper is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'MongoDatabase.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.mongodb.scala.bson.
[Error] /app/src/main/scala/com/example/App.scala:16:30: Symbol 'term org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value org.mongodb.scala.Document'.
Make sure that term Document is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.
[Error] /app/src/main/scala/com/example/App.scala:16:38: <notype> does not take parameters
[Error] /app/src/main/scala/com/example/App.scala:21:5: Symbol 'term org.mongodb.scala.bson.conversions.package' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection.filter'.
Make sure that term package is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'MongoCollection.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.mongodb.scala.bson.conversions.
5 errors found

> Task :app:compileScala FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
1 actionable task: 1 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a similar issue for my Scala application with the exception shown below:

```
Symbol 'term org.mongodb.scala.bson.DefaultHelper' is missing from the classpath
This symbol is required by 'value org.mongodb.scala.MongoDatabase.e'. 
Make sure that term DefaultHelper is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with -Ylog-classpath. 
A full rebuild may help if 'MongoDatabase.class' ...
```

My specific application using `scala-library` 2.12 with `mongo-scala-driver_2.12` 4.11 was resolved by downgrading the driver to version 4.3.2.

As I understand, not all versions of the MongoDB Scala driver are compatible with specific Scala versions. I did trial and error until it worked by following the compatibility table from the link below:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/scala/#language-compatibility